# How to serve .ejs view with Nginx in AWS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx

I have a Node app with an EJS view (/views/index.ejs) in my Node project directory. It is working well when I run the file /server.js using nodemon in my local.

Now I'm trying to deploy the Node app in AWS. So I created the EC2 instance and installed Nginx to reverse the proxy to my Node app. **The problem is I'm still seeing the Nginx welcome page instead of the Node app.**

**Here is the** `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
server {

    root ~/mynodeapp/views

    index index.ejs index.html index.htm 

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

**Here is the** `~/mynodeapp/server.js`

```
const app = require('./app');
const port = 3001;
const host = 'localhost/'

const server = app.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`Node server listening to ${server.address().port}`);
})
```

I'm using PM2 to run the Node app and when I put the command `systemctl status pm2-ec2-user`, it says `active (running)`

**Here are the things that I have tried so far.**

I tried to change the root of the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` from `/usr/share/nginx/html` to `~/mynodeapp/views` but then it shows `404`

I tried to enable the site using the following command

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. there is no extra work for this but making sure that

```
// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// use res.render to load up an ejs view file

// index page
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('pages/index');
});
```

this two line of code.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application